# Collecting specific elements from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying restructure an array and build another one. Tried to use `filter`, `map`, but couldn't achieved that. There are some factors in array and it's ratings (the 5 elements of object from the beginning). I should collect them in another array. I have an array like this.

```
[{
  "carryRating": 21,
  "distanceRating": 72,
  "obHavoYogingarchilikQorVaHKRating": 74,
  "obHavoQuruqRating": 40,
  "yetkazibBeruvchiningMoliyaviyAhvoliRating": 32,
  "id": 1,
  "direction": "A",
  "distance": "90.55",
  "carry": "365",
  "obHavoQuruq": "50",
  "yetkazibBeruvchiningMoliyaviyAhvoli": "56",
  "obHavoYogingarchilikQorVaHK": "58"
}, {
  "carryRating": 35,
  "distanceRating": 74,
  "obHavoYogingarchilikQorVaHKRating": 71,
  "obHavoQuruqRating": 29,
  "yetkazibBeruvchiningMoliyaviyAhvoliRating": 55,
  "id": 2,
  "direction": "B",
  "distance": "82.46",
  "carry": "589",
  "obHavoQuruq": "36",
  "yetkazibBeruvchiningMoliyaviyAhvoli": "98",
  "obHavoYogingarchilikQorVaHK": "65"
}, {
  "carryRating": 19,
  "distanceRating": 76,
  "obHavoYogingarchilikQorVaHKRating": 90,
  "obHavoQuruqRating": 17,
  "yetkazibBeruvchiningMoliyaviyAhvoliRating": 11,
  "id": 3,
  "direction": "C",
  "distance": "76.16",
  "carry": "326",
  "obHavoQuruq": "21",
  "yetkazibBeruvchiningMoliyaviyAhvoli": "20",
  "obHavoYogingarchilikQorVaHK": "23"
}, {
  "carryRating": 25,
  "distanceRating": 78,
  "obHavoYogingarchilikQorVaHKRating": 65,
  "obHavoQuruqRating": 14,
  "yetkazibBeruvchiningMoliyaviyAhvoliRating": 2,
  "id": 4,
  "direction": "D",
  "distance": "72.11",
  "carry": "421",
  "obHavoQuruq": "17",
  "yetkazibBeruvchiningMoliyaviyAhvoli": "3",
  "obHavoYogingarchilikQorVaHK": "78"
}]
```

I want to restructure it like this:

```
const newData = [
  {
    factor: "carry",
    firstElementOfArray: 21, // it's carryRating 
    secondElementOfArray: 35,
    thirdElementOfArray: 19,
    fourthElementOfArray: 25
  },
  {
    factor: "distance",
    firstElementOfArray: 72, // it's distanceRating
    secondElementOfArray: 74,
    thirdElementOfArray: 76,
    fourthElementOfArray: 78
  },
  {
    factor: "obHavoQuruq",
    firstElementOfArray: 40, // it's obHavoQuruqRating
    secondElementOfArray: 29,
    thirdElementOfArray: 17,
    fourthElementOfArray: 14
  },
  {
    factor: "yetkazibBeruvchiningMoliyaviyAhvoli",
    firstElementOfArray: 32, // it's yetkazibBeruvchiningMoliyaviyAhvoliRating
    secondElementOfArray: 55,
    thirdElementOfArray: 11,
    fourthElementOfArray: 2
  },
  {
    factor: "obHavoYogingarchilikQorVaHK",
    firstElementOfArray: 74, // it's obHavoYogingarchilikQorVaHKRating
    secondElementOfArray: 71,
    thirdElementOfArray: 90,
    fourthElementOfArray: 65
  },
]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What attempt have you made to solve this yourself? SO isn't here to write your code for you.

Comment: Why are the keys named that way? Doesn't seem very dynamic. It's hard to create new keys based on the number of elements in the array. Will it always have a fixed length or are you expecting `eleventhElement`, `twentySecondElement` etc

Comment: Might be a *don't do X, do Y* comment, but doesn't it make more sense to make the result a map of arrays? `{ carry: [21, 35, 19, 25], distance: [72, 74, 76, 78], ... }`

Comment: I tried for several days, but couldn't accomplish. After that, I asked here

Comment: Yess, the number of keys have no fixed length. It would be more or less.

Comment: Is it necessary to have this format for keys and why? It's hard to convert a number to ordinal numeral form (first, second etc). Why not have `{ factor: "obHavoQuruq", values: [21, 35, 19, 25 ] }` Or `{ carry: [21, 35, 19, 25] }`. It's easier to loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd solve it by mapping keys with properties, and iterating over them.
This solution does require you to have a fixed number of items in the input array, but it could be expanded with some kind of "translation" from [x] to 'x-thElementOfArray' if needed as well.

```js
let input = [{
  "carryRating": 21,
  "distanceRating": 72,
  "obHavoYogingarchilikQorVaHKRating": 74,
  "obHavoQuruqRating": 40,
  "yetkazibBeruvchiningMoliyaviyAhvoliRating": 32,
  "id": 1,
  "direction": "A",
  "distance": "90.55",
  "carry": "365",
  "obHavoQuruq": "50",
  "yetkazibBeruvchiningMoliyaviyAhvoli": "56",
  "obHavoYogingarchilikQorVaHK": "58"
}, {
  "carryRating": 35,
  "distanceRating": 74,
  "obHavoYogingarchilikQorVaHKRating": 71,
  "obHavoQuruqRating": 29,
  "yetkazibBeruvchiningMoliyaviyAhvoliRating": 55,
  "id": 2,
  "direction": "B",
  "distance": "82.46",
  "carry": "589",
  "obHavoQuruq": "36",
  "yetkazibBeruvchiningMoliyaviyAhvoli": "98",
  "obHavoYogingarchilikQorVaHK": "65"
}, {
  "carryRating": 19,
  "distanceRating": 76,
  "obHavoYogingarchilikQorVaHKRating": 90,
  "obHavoQuruqRating": 17,
  "yetkazibBeruvchiningMoliyaviyAhvoliRating": 11,
  "id": 3,
  "direction": "C",
  "distance": "76.16",
  "carry": "326",
  "obHavoQuruq": "21",
  "yetkazibBeruvchiningMoliyaviyAhvoli": "20",
  "obHavoYogingarchilikQorVaHK": "23"
}, {
  "carryRating": 25,
  "distanceRating": 78,
  "obHavoYogingarchilikQorVaHKRating": 65,
  "obHavoQuruqRating": 14,
  "yetkazibBeruvchiningMoliyaviyAhvoliRating": 2,
  "id": 4,
  "direction": "D",
  "distance": "72.11",
  "carry": "421",
  "obHavoQuruq": "17",
  "yetkazibBeruvchiningMoliyaviyAhvoli": "3",
  "obHavoYogingarchilikQorVaHK": "78"
}];

let propertyMapping = {
  carry: "carryRating",
  distance: "distanceRating",
  obHavoQuruq: "obHavoQuruqRating",
  yetkazibBeruvchiningMoliyaviyAhvoli: "yetkazibBeruvchiningMoliyaviyAhvoliRating",
  obHavoYogingarchilikQorVaHK: "obHavoYogingarchilikQorVaHKRating"
};

let output = Object.keys(propertyMapping).map(key => ({
    factor: key,
  firstElementOfArray: input[0][propertyMapping[key]],
  secondElementOfArray: input[1][propertyMapping[key]],
  thirdElementOfArray: input[2][propertyMapping[key]],
  fourthElementOfArray: input[3][propertyMapping[key]]
}));

console.log(output);
```

### Update

Alternatively, as you added that the source data will not always contain 4 items, it would be better to use a different output format (as proposed in the comments as well).

For example:

```js
let output = Object.keys(propertyMapping).map(key => ({
  factor: key,
  items: input.map(it => it[propertyMapping[key]])
}));
```

or

```js
let output = Object.keys(propertyMapping).reduce((prev, key) => ({ ...prev,
  [key]: input.map(it => it[propertyMapping[key]])
}), {})
```

Comment: @BB. You have mentioend *the number of keys have no fixed length*. This code will get 4 elements all the time.

Comment: Do u have any suggestions? I have planned to do it on myself. Just needed the method. If you have any suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: @BB. i've added some more dynamic solutions in the answer above

Comment: These dynamic methods didn't provided same structure as static one.